# Dual space is separable

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $Y$ be a closed subspace of $X$. Suppose that $X^*$ is separable. Prove that $Y^*$ is separable.

**Attempt:** Since $X^*$ is separable then we can conclude that $X$ is separable. If I could prove that $Y$ is reflexive (which I don't think is true) I could easily deduce that $Y^*$ is separable.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Well why would $Y$ be reflexive? this would be like claiming that every subspace of a space with separable dual is reflexive. But what about $X=Y=c_0$? we have that $X^*=\ell^1$ which is separable but $X^{**}=\ell^\infty$ which is not canonically isomorphic to $c_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{\varphi_n\}\subset X^*$ be a countable set that is dense in $X^*$. We claim that the restrictions $\{\varphi_n\vert_Y\}\subset Y^*$ form a dense subset of $Y^*$. Indeed, let $\psi\in Y^*$ be a bounded functional and let $\varepsilon>0$. Our goal is to find $m\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $\|\psi-\varphi_m\vert_Y\|<\varepsilon$, so this is what we are trying to do now.

By the Hahn-Banach extension therorem we can find a functional $\Psi\in X^*$ so that $\Psi\vert_Y=\psi$. Now since $\{\varphi_n\}$ is dense in $X^*$ we can find $m\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $\|\Psi-\varphi_m\|<\varepsilon$. In other words,
$$\sup_{x\in X,\|x\|\leq1}|\Psi(x)-\varphi_m(x)|<\varepsilon$$

Therefore,
$$\sup_{y\in Y,\|y\|\leq1}|\psi(y)-\varphi_m(y)|<\varepsilon$$
so $\|\psi-\varphi_m\vert_Y\|<\varepsilon$, as we wanted.

Comment: Very nice answer. Where was the hypothesis that $Y$ is closed used?

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis nowhere!

Comment: Interesting. The question was given as is in a past exam. I think it is subtly used to guarantee that $Y^*$ is a Banach space though.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis sometimes an extra assumption is added so the setting feels more natural somehow. You are doing the right thing by looking for the part where the assumption is being used.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer!